# I can't see or edit MySQL stored procedures in NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, netbeans

I can connect to MySQL database (5.7.23) from NetBeans (8.2) using JDBC (MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, mysql-connector-java-5.1.23). I can see tables and views, execute SQL statements and everything else with database but I cannot see or edit stored procedures (or functions) in NetBeans. I have them inside database, I can see and manage them in MySQL Workbench but cannot see them in NetBeans (folder "Procedures" in NetBeans is empty). What could be the problem?

Left in NetBeans, right in Workbench:

[image: in NetBeans]
[image: in Workbench]

I have 64-bit Windows 10 Pro (1709), 64-bit NetBeans 8.2 (PHP) and 64-bit MySQL 5.7.14 (from WAMP).

Comment: You may want to consider updating to a newer version of the driver, 5.1.23 is a pretty old version of MySQL Connector/J

Comment: I updated MySQL connector/J to 5.1.47 and still was not able to see procedures in NetBeans. Then I updated connector to version 8.0.13, should be the very last version, the same thing, I cannot see my procedures.

Comment: Could somebody else confirm to have the same issue with procedures in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibly two reasons:

### 1. User doesn't have access to mysql.proc

NetBeans uses something like that to get the list of procedures and functions ([see the source code](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/search?q=%22from%20mysql%22&unscoped_q=%22from%20mysql%22)):

```
SELECT 
    db, name, type, param_list, returns, body
FROM
    mysql.proc
WHERE
    TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' OR TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
```

Try to execute the query in NetBeans and see the result.

See the screenshot. On the first one, the user root has access to the mysql schema and you can see all system schemas including the mysql. On the second one, the user has access only to the information_schema and performance_schema and can not see procedures and functions:

[image]

Try to add to your user access to the MySQL schema. In workbench go to Server -> Users and Privileges -> Schema Privileges:

[image]

### 2. There is no mysql.proc in 8.0 mysql

Again, NetBeans uses `mysql.pros` extensively to get metadata about procedures and funcstions (see in [source code](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/search?q=%22from%20mysql%22&unscoped_q=%22from%20mysql%22)). I suppose a simple workaround we can get is to create a view that would mimic [the behavior of original](https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/) `mysql.proc`:

```
CREATE VIEW mysql.proc AS
    SELECT 
        ROUTINE_SCHEMA AS db,
        ROUTINE_NAME AS name,
        ROUTINE_TYPE AS type,
        ROUTINE_DEFINITION AS body,
        CONCAT(DTD_IDENTIFIER,
                ' CHARSET ',
                CHARACTER_SET_NAME) AS returns,
        (SELECT 
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(parameter_name, ' ', dtd_identifier))
            FROM
                information_schema.parameters p
            WHERE
                p.specific_name = outertable.routine_name
                    AND ordinal_position > 0) AS param_list
    FROM
        information_schema.routines outertable
```

After creating a view we can view procedures and functions from NetBeans 11.2 and view their bodies and param list. Also, I would not recommend editing procedures using NetBeans because it can't get full metadata. For example, it could not get declaration options such as `DETERMINISTIC SQL SECURITY INVOKER`.

Comment: I used root user and go the following response;

`[Warning, Error code 1.146, SQLState 42S02] Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist

[1:1] Failed in 0 s.
[Exception, Error code 1.146, SQLState 42S02] Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
  Line 1, column 1


Execution finished after 0,015 s, 1 error occurred.`

Comment: Seems that MySQL from version 8.0 does not have mysql.proc table (see https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/) I use MySQL 8.0.19 (not MariaDB)

Comment: Obviously this part of code inside NetBeans should be replaced with:
`SELECT routine_name,routine_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE routine_type IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE')` (if this is code responsible for fetching MySQL routines into navigation tree)

Comment: @sbrbot, exactly! I think we should fire a bug. As a workaround you could try to create a view and call it mysql.proc and  reference it to information_schema.routines. Is it possible?

Comment: Indeed, clever try, as you suggested, I successfully created mysql.proc view showing NAME and TYPE of routines from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but unfortunately NetBeans still does not show procedures in tree. I can select from view in NetBeans console and see procedures and functions but they do not populate tree. So the code that you pointed before probably is not the one responsible for this purpose. See above in my prev post.

Comment: @sbrbot, you could try this `create view mysql.proc as  SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA as db, ROUTINE_NAME as name,ROUTINE_TYPE as type FROM information_schema.routines;` but I think the problem more complex. With the view I can see a procedure but can not see the body. We should map also param_list and routine_body and returns. Not sure if NetBeans could handle it. See [this](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/0f2e98d513deaedccef831ee9cfc08d09f3650b6/ide/db.metadata.model/src/org/netbeans/modules/db/metadata/model/jdbc/mysql/MySQLSchema.java#L57)

Comment: Voila!!! It works now!!! I knew that NetBeans has to filter shema owner in order to fetch only owner's routines (like in Oracle). Seems that that you found some other part of NetBean's code with db column!!! :-)

Comment: Wow man, great job! You realy deserverd your bounty points. Can you point to the new code where this query is used inside NetBeans?

Comment: @sbrbot, you can search in the repo. There are not so many places where it is [used](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/search?q=%22from+mysql%22&unscoped_q=%22from+mysql%22)

Comment: I reported this bug long time ago (when NetBeans still was v8.2) - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1603

Comment: Just FYI - according to your hints I made bug fix on my own and made a pull request for this change in NetBean's repo on GitHub. We could expect this fix to be released in next NetBeans version.

Comment: Three years after the first GitHub pull request there's an epilogue, it was merged (https://github.com/apache/netbeans/commit/e4fd2324b86f44afe9de596542d95f97727b9f20) and the patch will be released in next version of NetBeans 17 :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using netbeans 8.2 patch 2 and can show store procedure

[image]

And This is info netbeans which I'm using

[image]

I think you should be re-install full version netbeans.

Comment: I've got exactly the same NetBeans version (Build 201609300101)

Comment: What MySQL version and connector version do you use?

Comment: I use connect version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
MySQL version 5.5.38

Comment: No way, I downloaded the database 5.5.62 and JDBC Connector 5.1.8 from this FTP site http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/mysql/Downloads/ and installed them. But still does not work, so it's not up to versions!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite annoying that I still haven't found the solution for this problem. This question is more than one year old. NetBeans changed from 8.2, 9, 10, now I use 11.2 and still this functionality does not work! I changed MySQL versions, NetBeans versions, JDBC driver versions!!! I must be related to regional settings of my machine that disrupts NetBeans!

[image: Stored procedures in NetBeans]

On screenshot one can see that `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` in NetBeans shows the list of my stored procedures inside database but NetBeans does not show them in navigation tree!

It's really awkward that nobody else encountered this NetBeans strange behaviour.

[image: mysql.proc]

Comment: please update the original post. [1] Is there any jdbc or mysql related messages in View - IDE Log when clicking to procedure node in netbeans? [2] can you see other procedures of functions in other databases?

Answer (score 0):

The proof that it is the solution.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.proc TO '<user_name>'@'<host_name>';

Comment: You should read comments: https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/